# Simply this exponential integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am trying to simplify of this:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}e^{-\lambda x}\,dx.$$

Maybe I should separate these equation into two exponential integral function?
But it will ended up with infinite minus infinite?
please give me some help or advices, thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it but you probably can separate the integral into two indefinite integrals, and evaluate them separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write ${1-e^{-x}\over x}$ as $\int_0^1 e^{-tx}\,dt$, reverse the order of integration in the resulting double integral, then integrate.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Now fixed.

Comment: thanks a lot! I really appreciate that!