# Simplify an exponential integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function, exponentiation

I want to solve this :

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}e^{-\lambda x^{\alpha}}dx$

I had asked a similar problems yesterday, like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474834/simply-this-exponential-integral)
,but we get power of alpha of x and I cannot use Frullani's theorem this time.
please give me some help or advices!thanks a lot!!

Comment: Where is the equation ? You need a symbol "=" to call it an equation.

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake.I have fixed it.thanks!